# Using Inject in a Module using Mapbinder in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using Guice MapBinder to bind different implementations of an interface to a specific key. Problem is, I need to inject some dependencies in these bindings. I don't think this is possible due to the fact that I need to initialize the Module by doing this:

```
Guice.createInjector(new SomeModule());
```

Is it possible somehow?

EDIT: More complete example:

Interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
  String getName();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class SomeImplementation imlements SomeInterface{
   @Inject
   public SomeImplementation(SomeDependency someDep){
       //this needs to be injected
   }

   @Override
   public String getName(){
      //getNameFromDependency
   }
}
```

Module:

```
public class SomeModule extends AbstractModule {

 @Override
 protected void configure() {
   MapBinder<String, SecureToken> binder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, SomeInterface.class);

    //bind stuff
   }
}
```

EDIT2:
Problem is, I work with Reflection to get all Implementations of an Interface. To call the method "getName", I need to call newInstance. This seems to be the problem... :-/

```
protected void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, SomeInterface> binder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, SecureToken.class);
    try {
      Set<Class<? extends SomeInterface>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SecureToken.class);
      for (Class<? extends SecureToken> clazz : subTypes) {
        SomeInterface someInterface = clazz.newInstance();
        String name = someInterface.getName();
        binder.addBinding(name).toInstance(someInterface);
      }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you show a more complete example of what you are attempting to do?

Comment: I still don't see the issue. `binder.addBinding("fred").to(SomeImplementation.class);`

Comment: To be honest this feels like a bad design. If it had to be this way I think I'd expose a SomeInterface factory which was Guice away are exposed a `get(String)`.

Comment: Yep, I the longer I think about the design, the more I also belive it's totally bullcrap. I guess, I will throw all the fancy reflection stuff away..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are no longer "binding", you have (IMO) a factory. So you should expose it as such. 
Note: You can inject the injector which (for factories) is a perfectly fine thing to do.